# jQuery append and remove dynamic table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, tablerow, dom-traversal

I can add many rows for a table,
but I can't remove many rows.
I only can remove 1 row per sequential add.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addCF").click(function(){
        $("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Custom Field</label></th><td><input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldName" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="Input Name" /> &nbsp; <input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldValue" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
        $("#remCF").on('click',function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
    });
});
</script>

<table class="form-table" id="customFields">
<tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Custom Field</label></th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldName" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="Input Name" /> &nbsp;
        <input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldValue" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /> &nbsp;
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addCF">Add</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can see the code at http://jsfiddle.net/3AJcj/

I need help.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You only can have one unique ID per page. Change those IDs to classes, and change the jQuery selectors as well.

Also, move the .on() outside of the .click() function, as you only need to set it once.

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/3AJcj/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".addCF").click(function(){
        $("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Custom Field</label></th><td><input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldName" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="Input Name" /> &nbsp; <input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldValue" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
    });
    $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks it really works
but if I use .live() it works too but with old jquery library http://jsfiddle.net/gfpoow/fgZF3/

Answer (score 11):

You can dynamically add and delete table rows like this in the image using jQuery..
[image]

Here is html part...

```
<form id='students' method='post' name='students' action='index.php'>

    <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()"/></th>
        <th>S. No</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Tamil</th>
        <th>English</th>
        <th>Computer</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td><input type='text' id='first_name' name='first_name[]'/></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='last_name' name='last_name[]'/></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='tamil' name='tamil[]'/></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='english' name='english[]'/> </td>
        <td><input type='text' id='computer' name='computer[]'/></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='total' name='total[]'/> </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <button type="button" class='delete'>- Delete</button>
    <button type="button" class='addmore'>+ Add More</button>
    <p>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' class='but'/></p>
</form>
```

Next need to include jquery...

```
<script src='jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
```

Finally script which adds the table rows...

```
<script>
  var i=2;
  $(".addmore").on('click',function(){
    var data="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td>"+i+".</td>";
        data +="<td><input type='text' id='first_name"+i+"' name='first_name[]'/></td> <td><input type='text' id='last_name"+i+"' name='last_name[]'/></td><td><input type='text' id='tamil"+i+"' name='tamil[]'/></td><td><input type='text' id='english"+i+"' name='english[]'/></td><td><input type='text' id='computer"+i+"' name='computer[]'/></td><td><input type='text' id='total"+i+"' name='total[]'/></td></tr>";
        $('table').append(data);
        i++;
});
</script>
```

Also refer [demo](http://demo.smarttutorials.net/auto_table/) & [tutorial](http://www.smarttutorials.net/add-remove-table-rows-jquery/) for this dynamically add & remove table rows

Answer (score 4):

Change ID to class :

```
$("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Custom Field</label></th><td><input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldName" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="Input Name" /> &nbsp; <input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldValue" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');

$(".remCF").on('click',function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7BHDm/1/

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other answers, I'd like to improve the removal, to something more generic:

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

This would be much better than using `$(this).parent().parent().remove();`, because it doesn't depend on the depth of the element. So, the structure of the row becomes much more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems here

1. Id should be unique in a page
2. For dynamic elements, you need to use event delegation using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Ex

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addCF").click(function(){
        $("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Custom Field</label></th><td><input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldName" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="Input Name" /> &nbsp; <input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldValue" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
    });

    $("#customFields").on('click', '#remCF', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u4ZV6/1/)

See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u4ZV6/2/) where id properties are removed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addCF").click(function(){
        $("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Custom Field</label></th><td><input type="text" class="code" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="Input Name" /> &nbsp; <input type="text" class="code" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
    });

    $("#customFields").on('click', '.remCF', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

**live view** [Link Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashikjs/q81w4hdr/6/)

vary simple way you can solve it .....
take a look my new collected code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".add-row").click(function(){
                var name = $("#name").val();
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td></tr>";
                $("table tbody").append(markup);
            });

            // Find and remove selected table rows
            $(".delete-row").click(function(){
                $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
                    if($(this).is(":checked")){
                        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add-row").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td></tr>";
    $("table tbody").append(markup);
  });

  // Find and remove selected table rows
  $(".delete-row").click(function() {
    $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
form input,
button {
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: #fff;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
table th,
table td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
body {
  background: #ccc;
}
.add-row,
.delete-row {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email">
  <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
</form>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="record">
      </td>
      <td>Peter Parker</td>
      <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try that:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var add = '<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Custom Field</label></th><td>';
                add+= '<input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldName" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="Input Name" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                add+= '<input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldValue" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />&nbsp;';
                add+= '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>';

    $(".addCF").click(function(){ $("#customFields").append(add); });

    $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
        var inx = $('.remCF').index(this);
        $('tr').eq(inx+1).remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please format your code to make it more readable. You could take a look at [this markdown help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Apart from formatting, it would be nice if you would add a description instead of only code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var add = '<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Custom Field</label></th><td>';
        add+= '<input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldName" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="Input Name" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        add+= '<input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldValue" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />&nbsp;';
        add+= '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>';

        $(".addCF").click(function(){ $("#customFields").append(add); });

        $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
            var inx = $('.remCF').index(this);
            $('tr').eq(inx+1).remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Addrow();
})
$("#add").click(function () {
    Addrow();
})
rowcount = $("#tbuser td").closest.length;
function Addrow() {
    rowcount++;
    debugger
    var markup = "<tr><td></td><td><input type='text' name='stuclass' id='stuclass'/></td><td><select name='Institute' class='Institute_" + rowcount + "'></select></td><td><input type='text' name='obtmark' id='obtmark'/></td><td><input type='text' name='totalmark' id='totalmark'/></td><td><input type='text' name='per' id='per'/></td><td><button type='button' id='delete' onclick='deleterow(this);'>DELETE</button></td></tr>";
    $(".tbuser tbody").append(markup);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("bindinst", "Home")',
        data: '',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            $(".Institute_" + rowcount).empty();
            $(".Institute_" + rowcount).append('<option Value="">--Select--</option>');
            $.each(data, function (i, result) {

                $(".Institute_" + rowcount).append('<option Value="' + result.Value + '">' + result.Text + '</option>');
            });
        },

    });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>`enter code here`
        $(document).ready(function () {
var result=1;
$('input').keyup(function(){`enter code here`
     $('tr').each(function () {
         var sum = $(this).find('td.combat').text();
         var combat = $(this).find('input.combat').val();
         if (!isNaN(sum) && sum.length !== 0 && !isNaN(combat) && combat.length !== 0) {
                 result = parseFloat(sum)*parseFloat(combat);
             }

         $(this).find('.total-combat').html(result);
        });
    });
 $('.add').click(function(){
        var sno = $(this).parent().siblings('.sno').text();
        var cust = $(this).parent().siblings('.cust').text();
        var price = $(this).parent().siblings('td.combat').text();
        var rowValue = [];
        $(this).closest('tr').find("input").each(function() {
                  rowValue.push($(this).val());
                  return $(this).val(); 
                 });

         var rowValue1 = [];
        $(this).closest('tr').find("span").each(function() {
                  rowValue1.push($(this).text());
                  return $(this).val(); 
                 });

                    var markup = "<tr><td class='sno'>" + sno + "</td><td class='custname'>" + cust +"</td><td class='price'>" + price +"</td><td><input type='text' class='newtext' value="+ rowValue[0] +"></td><td class='total'>" + rowValue1[0] +"</td><td><input type='submit' class='update' value='upd'><input type='button' class='del' value='del'></td></tr>";



        var rightcol = $(this).closest('tr').find(".cust");
        var row_count =  $('.tbl1 tbody tr').length;
        alert(row_count);

        if (row_count == 0) {


                        $(".tbl1 tbody").append(markup);


        }
        else
        {
            var tes=0;
            $('.tbl1 tbody tr').each(function(){
                        var leftcol = $(this).find(".custname");

                            if(rightcol.html() == leftcol.html()) {
                                alert(leftcol.html()+"-----------------"+rightcol.html());
                                $(this).find('.sno').text(sno);
                                $(this).find('.custname').text(cust);
                                $(this).find('.price').text(price);
                                $(this).find('.newtext').val(rowValue[0]);
                                $(this).find('.total').text(rowValue1[0]);
                                tes++;
                     }
            });
                if(tes==0){
                    $(".tbl1 tbody").append(markup);
                }    


        }

});
            $(".tb").on("click", ".update", function(e) {
                var rowValues = [];
                                    $(this).closest('tr').find("input").each(function() {
                                  rowValues.push($(this).val());
                                  return $(this).val(); 

                                 });
                    var total=$(this).closest('tr').find('.total').text();
                    var right_cols = $(this).closest('tr').find(".custname");

                $('.tbl tbody tr').each(function(){
                        var row = $(this);
                        var left_cols = $(this).find(".cust");
                            if(left_cols.html() == right_cols.html()) {

                                $(this).find('.text').val(rowValues[0]);
                                $(this).find('.total-combat').text(total);
                             }
                         });



        });         
                $(".tb").on("keyup", "input", function() {
                 $('tr').each(function () {
                     var sum = $(this).find('td.price').text();
                     var combat = $(this).find('input.newtext').val();
                     if (!isNaN(sum) && sum.length !== 0 && !isNaN(combat) && combat.length !== 0) {
                            result = parseFloat(sum)*parseFloat(combat);
                         }

                        $(this).find('.total').html(result);
                    });
                });
         $(".tb").on("click", ".del", function() {
                  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
              });
});


    </script>
<style>

    .table_style {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    }
    table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table tr td{
    width: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #ff751a;
    padding: 5px;
    }
    table tr th{
    border: 5px solid #79ff4d;
    padding: 5px;
    }
    input{
        width:35px;
    }
    .tbl1{
        margin-top: 50px;
        border: 0px solid #cdcdcd;
    }
    .btn{
        float:left;
    }
    </style>
        <title>E-Commerce-Table</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="table_style">
    <caption>Price-List</caption>
<table class="tbl">
    <tr>
        <th>S.No</th>
        <th>P.Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Qnty</th>
        <th>Rate</th>   
        <th>action</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="sno">1</td>
        <td class="cust">A</td>
        <td class="combat">5</td>
        <td class="tester"><input type="number" id="qnty1" name="Qnty" value="0" class="combat text"></td>
        <td><span class="total-combat"></span></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" class="add"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="sno">2</td>
        <td class="cust">B</td>
        <td class="combat">8</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="qnty2" name="Qnty" value="0" class="combat text"></td>
        <td><span class="total-combat"></span></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" class="add"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="sno">3</td>
        <td class="cust">C</td>
        <td class="combat">7</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="qnty3" name="Qnty" value="0" class="combat text"></td>
        <td><span class="total-combat"></span></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" class="add"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="sno">4</td>
        <td class="cust">D</td>
        <td class="combat">2</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="qnty4" name="Qnty" value="0" class="combat text"></td>
        <td><span class="total-combat"></span></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" class="add"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

</table>

     <table class="tbl1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>P.Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Qnty</th>
                <th>Rate</th>
                <th>action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tb">

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" name="addtocart" id="btn">Add-to-cart</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   // dynamically generate row by clicking plus icon
        $(document).on('click', '.add_row', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var configParamsObj = {
                placeholder: 'Select an option...', // Place holder text to place in the select
                minimumResultsForSearch: 3 // Overrides default of 15 set above
            };
            var $thisTable = $(this).closest('table').find('tbody');
            var copyRow = $thisTable.find('tr:first');
            var hasSelect2 = $thisTable.find('.singleSelectExample').length;
            if (hasSelect2 !== 0) $thisTable.find(".singleSelectExample").select2('destroy');
            $thisTable.prepend(`<tr>${copyRow.html()}</tr>`);
            if (hasSelect2 !== 0) {
                $thisTable.find('.singleSelectExample').select2().next().next().remove();
                $thisTable.find('select.singleSelectExample').select2(configParamsObj);
            }
            var $thisRow = $thisTable.find('tr:first');
            $thisRow.find('select').val('').trigger('change');
            $thisRow.find("input.datepicker").each(function (i, key) {
                var format = $(key).data('format');
                $(key).datetimepicker({
                    format: format,
                    showClear: true
                });
            });
            $thisRow.find("input.customdatepicker").each(function (i, key) {
                var format = $(key).data('format');
                $(key).datetimepicker({
                    format: format,
                    showClear: true,
                    minDate: new Date()
                });
            });
            $thisRow.find("input[type=text]").val("");
            $thisRow.find("input[type=hidden]").val("");
            $thisRow.find("input[type=number]").val("");
        });

        // remove added rows
        $(document).on("click", "a.removeRow ", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var thisRow = $(this).closest("tr");
            var totalRows = thisRow.closest('tbody').find('tr').length;
            if (totalRows > 1) thisRow.remove();
        });
```