# Javascript Form Display and Edit

Tags: javascript, html, oop

I want to take the form data as javascript variables and store it in an object then as the form submits show that data into a table below the form with edit and delete button beside it.So i want to do it using OOPS concept in javascript and there should not be any server side scripting.this is pure client side scripting where only HTML &  javascript doing all this.Please help me out with this with only one field in the form as like Name...
When onclick store the name to some object like person which can be editable and delete..

Comment: var usr = document.getElementById('user').value; I have tried using this,displayed the data & also given edit functionality which also edits but when you try adding new name then it should add up the existing name and not replacing the existing one..

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript you want to do something along the lines of (this will only work if you're using jQuery).

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#placeToStoreName").val($("#name").val());
});
```

I won't write your HTML for you, but this should give you a starting point for the client side code.

Note this doesn't store it as it's own variable. If you want to do that then you can use

```
var name = $("#name").val();
```

This approach assumes that you are assigning an id to the field you wish to save. If you're not then you need to research using javascript to access the nodes within a form and extract that data.

Comment: OP doesn't seem to have well hold of javascript itself, showing JQuery code is just going to confuse him , better start with pure JS and then you can encourage him to learn JQuery :)

Comment: var usr = document.getElementById('user').value;
I have tried using this,displayed the data & also given edit functionality which also edits but when you try adding new name then it should add up the existing name and not replacing the existing one..

Answer (score 0):

Fetch and store all form data into variables when you submit form using jquery code given below

```
$("button").click(function(){
$("#name").val($("#name").val());
$("#email").val($("#email").val());
});
```

And use the this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183231/jquery-append-and-remove-dynamic-table-row) link to create rows of table dynamically.