# How I remove table dynamic row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm following code from 
[jquery append and remove dynamic table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183231/jquery-append-and-remove-dynamic-table-row)
(http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/3AJcj/2/)

I already organized my table. 
But remove function didn't work, how I change this code?
I can't understand about `$(this).parent().parent().remove();` code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".addCF").click(function(){
  $("#addTg").after('<tr><td class="tg-yw4l" ><input type="text"></td><td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2" ><input type="text"></td><td class="tg-yw4l" ><input type="text"></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF" >Remove</a></td></tr>');
 });
     $("#addTg").on('click','.remCF',function(){
         $(this).parent().parent().remove();
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg">
   <tr>
    <td class="tg-mtwr">DATE</td>
    <td class="tg-mtwr" colspan="2" >CONTENTS</td>
    <td class="tg-mtwr">PRICE</td>
    <td class="tg-mtwr">BUTTON</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="addTg">
    <td class="tg-yw4l" ><input type="text"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2" ><input type="text"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" ><input type="text"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td colspan="5" style="border:0px solid #fff;">
   
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="addCF" >Add</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically added elements are not inside the `#addTg` which is the sibling of the element. So change the selector wth the parent table class selector.

Inside the handler `this` refers to the clicked dom object and **[`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** method is using to get the parent of the element. You can simplify it using **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** method which retrieves the element by traversing up through its ancestors.

Although `myFunction` is not defined in your code so remove `onclick="myFunction()"` from the button which is not necessary here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addCF").click(function() {
    $("#addTg").after('<tr><td class="tg-yw4l" ><input type="text"></td><td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2" ><input type="text"></td><td class="tg-yw4l" ><input type="text"></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF" >Remove</a></td></tr>');
  });
  $(".tg").on('click', '.remCF', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-mtwr">DATE</td>
    <td class="tg-mtwr" colspan="2">CONTENTS</td>
    <td class="tg-mtwr">PRICE</td>
    <td class="tg-mtwr">BUTTON</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="addTg">
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5" style="border:0px solid #fff;">

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button class="addCF">Add</button>
```

Comment: @user2458645 :glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you would like to remove the row when the "Remove" link gets clicked. That link looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">
```

So one could think the function you already have for removing the row should be triggered whenever an element with the class `remCF` is clicked:

```
$(".remCF").on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

However that wouldn't work because you create those links dynamically, so you would be binding a `click` event to something that not yet exists.

Instead of that, I would create the links with an `onclick` property that calls a function to delete the row.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".addCF").click(function() {
    $("#addTg").after('<tr><td class="tg-yw4l" ><input type="text"></td><td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2" ><input type="text"></td><td class="tg-yw4l" ><input type="text"></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteRow($(this));" class="remCF" >Remove</a></td></tr>');
  });
});

function deleteRow(elem) {
    elem.parent().parent().remove();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg">
   <tr>
    <td class="tg-mtwr">DATE</td>
    <td class="tg-mtwr" colspan="2" >CONTENTS</td>
    <td class="tg-mtwr">PRICE</td>
    <td class="tg-mtwr">BUTTON</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="addTg">
    <td class="tg-yw4l" ><input type="text"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2" ><input type="text"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" ><input type="text"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td colspan="5" style="border:0px solid #fff;">
   
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button class="addCF" >Add</button>
```

That way, when you click the "Remove" link it will call that function, and that function will do the following:

1. It will take the element passed as an argument to the function: $(this)
2. Then it will take it's parent: the cell where it's contained (`<td>`)
3. Then it will take the parent of that cell: the row where it's contained: (`<tr>`)
4. It will remove that element (the row)

Those 4 steps is what `elem.parent().parent().remove();` means.

And a shorter approach to do the same would be:

`elem.closest('tr').remove();`